# What's the rails way to post form data to a third party web service?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, forms, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a simple form with one text area that submits the string in the text area as JSON to an external web service. Here's what it looks like before the form is submitted:

[image: before]

And here's what it looks like after the form is submitted:

[image: after]

And here's the html.erb code that created the form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function call_service() {
    var data_to_send = document.getElementById("data_to_send").value;

    $.ajax({
      url : "http://externalservice.com",
      data : data_to_send,
      type : "POST",
      dataType : "json",
      contentType: "application/json"
    }).done(function(data) {
      // populate the table
    }).error(function(data) {
      // handle error
    });
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#table_div").hide();
  });
</script>

<!-- heading html redacted -->

<!-- <%= form_tag("http://externalservice.com", 
                      method: :post,
                      remote: true,
                      role: "form",
                      data: "json") do %> -->

<form role="form">
  <h4 class="form-heading">Enter Data:</h4>
    <%= text_area_tag("data_to_send", @data, 
                          rows: 5, 
                          class: "form-control",
                          style: "font-family: Monaco;") %>
    <p class="help-block">
      Here you can edit the JSON data or click "Generate" to just
      use the data that's already there.
    </p>
    <%= button_to_function("Generate Table!", "call_service(); this.blur()" ,class: "btn btn-primary") %>
<!-- <% end %> -->
</form>

<!-- table html redacted -->
```

Where the commented out `form_tag` is what I was trying to do before I just decided to make things work using jQuery and the `button_to_function` bit.

My question is how do I accomplish the same thing--a form that sends JSON data to an external service--the rails way? Whether that's with a `remote: true` form or otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

If the 3rd party webservice is REST compliant, you may want to give [ActiveResource](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html) a try.

Also read [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11059519/what-is-the-difference-between-activeresource-and-activemodel) for some more hints.

Comment: The web service isn't a full fledged resource. I really am only interested in it's return long enough to display it in a table on the same page. Mostly I'm just curious if there's a more rails way to accomplish what my hand-hacked Ajax call accomplishes. Thanks for the tips about ActiveResource though!